# How to parse from InputStream using Protocol Buffers when you don't know what is the concrete message type up front?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

In the [examples](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial) parsing is made like:

```
AddressBook addressBook = AddressBook.parseFrom(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
```

but that means that you must know what is the type of the expected message.

I have defined in my .proto file different messages like 'Login', 'Logout', etc. and generated the java file.

How do you handle the situation when you don't know what is the concrete message that is about to come? How do you parse it (from an InputStream for example)?

Is there some generic `parse` method in the generated file that "automagically" determines how to parse the message and return `Message` or `MessageLite`?

Comment: There's no `automagical` on this. You can design your system to recognize/handle multiple message formats (ie XML, JSON, etc), but you've mostly got to do this yourself.

Comment: I don't use multiple message formats like XML/JSON. I use the default binary writeTo() methods. But when I do `LoginMessage.writeTo` how to know on the other end that it is a LoginMessage comming so I can use `LoginMessage.parseFrom()`?

Answer (score 1):

Protobuf is basically just a serialization API. So there is no generic way of "knowing" which message it is.

I would try to use a message header uniquely identifying each message type. Maybe that would be enough for you.

Comment: Yes, I am already doing that. I've created `MessageContainer` message with `Any` type for the raw msg and int value for the type. Then and  I am using MessageRegister to register all my messages with the mentioned integer `type` and pack/unpack using the concrete types. I was just hoping that there is an existing solution.